# How to override element.style height

Tags: javascript, html, css, height

I am trying to change the height of a div in a calendar that I haven't written by myself. In firebug I see this for css:

```
element.style {
        height: 744px;
        width: 1463px;
        left: 0px;
        top: 81px;
       }
```

I have read that this will always override css and that it is a result from a js file. I tried to find the file with grep but I can't find it. I also tried to override divs height inside the html page like this:

```
  <style type="text/css">
      .dhx_cal_data p{
            height:900px !important;

          }

      .dhx_cal_data {
            height:900px !important;

       }

       #dhx_cal_data {
             height:900px !important;

        }
```

Html :

```
 <div class="dhx_cal_data" name="dhx_cal_data" id="dhx_cal_data" style="height:900px;">
                    <p class="para1">

  </div>
```

And also i tried to override it with javascript like this:

```
<script >

$(document).ready(function(){


var obj = document.getElementById('dhx_cal_data');
obj.style.height = "900px";
document.getElementById("dhx_cal_data").style["height"] = '900px';
 })
</script>
```

But nothing is working. Do you know how I can change it? Or maybe how I can find the file that creates this element.style?

Comment: You should put the `!important` before the semi-colon (`;`), not after

Comment: Not sure if you copied the code correctly:

it should be: height: 900px !important; instead of height:900px;!important

Comment: Yes you are right. I changed it but it didn't work.

Comment: Maybe problem in parent container of this div?

Comment: I changed parent container height but nothing again

Comment: Can you post complete code to http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: It's a total hack, but you could write your own jQuery function that redefines the height after the unknown javascript file does. Just put the jQuery code before the closing body tag. Granted, this is a terrible practice and should only be used if all of your other efforts fail.

Comment: Well I haven't done it before. I will try to copy the html code.

Comment: Ok I am sure it is not correct but this is what I copied. https://jsfiddle.net/nogrwt58/

Comment: @Longblog JQuery that changed the height? I have also used javascript when loading the page to change it but it didn't work.

Comment: Was your javascript at the bottom of the document, ensuring it loads last? It should work unless your javascript code is incorrect.

Comment: No it was in the beggining. Now it is working! Thank you! How do I select your answer

Comment: I see you use some template engine. Can you post result html code (from browser) to jsfiddle or pastebin?

Comment: I managed to change it with javascript before </body> tag

Comment: @BrAtMaria You can't mark my answer, since it's a comment. The most you can do is upvote the comment, but you probably need more rep for that. Here, I'll put it as an answer so you can mark the problem as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a total hack, but you could write your own jQuery function that redefines the height after the unknown javascript file does. Just put the jQuery code before the closing body tag. Granted, this is a terrible practice and should only be used if all of your other efforts fail.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `!important` before `;`.
2. See: http://jsfiddle.net/ahfo9cfc/1/ - JS works

Comment: I did but still not working. I think it has to do with this element.style that overrides my css in the file.

Comment: @BrAtMaria - the only way that an inline element style would override a class that had `!important` in it, would be if the inline style also had `!important` in it.  I suspect that there may be other elements in your HTML that also have size values applied to them, that are affecting your results.